# How to skip/exclude spec.ts and json files from sonar code coverage analysis - Angular 5

Tags: jasmine, sonarqube, angular5, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

Currently in SonarQube code coverage analysis it shows line coverage for spec.ts files(which are test files) also and I want to ignore/exclude all the spec.ts and JSON model files from SonarQube code coverage analysis.

Comment: You can set up something like: `sonar.exclusions=**\*spec.ts` `sonar.coverage.exclusions=**\*spec.ts` `sonar.cpd.exclusions=**\*spec.ts` Check this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/